# OnclientClick - server tag not well formed error

Tags: javascript, asp.net

OnClientClick = '<%# Eval("IsActive").ToString() == "True" ? "return confirm('Are you sure? This will remove the control from Brand-Mappings as well.');" : "" %>'

Hi guys, what i want to do over here is that i want to enable return confirm only when IsActice evaluates to true. I am getting server tag not formed error.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your single quotes (e.g `'` ), you have one pair of single quotes at the beginning of the `OnClientClick`, and then another pair in the `confirm()`. Try escaping the second pair for instance:

```
OnClientClick = '<%# Eval("IsActive").ToString() == "True" ? "return confirm(\"Are you sure? This will remove the control from Brand-Mappings as well.\");" : "" %>'
```

Comment: I didnt get the error. But not getting the confirmation prompt either. Please help.

Comment: Please show us your updated code? And also so use the View->Source of your new aspx file?

Comment: OnClientClick = '<%# Eval("IsActive").ToString() == "True" ? "return confirm(Are you sure? This will remove the control from Brand-Mappings as well.);" : "" %>'

Comment: @Blachshma Thanks man. I've spent 4 hours looking for solution till found your answer.